# How PrintWriter can write to byte stream, but BufferedWriter cannot?

Tags: java, io, printwriter, bufferedwriter, writer

To start with I will provide a piece of code with comments:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("test.txt");
//fos IS-A OutputStream as FileOutputStream extends OutputStream

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fos); //compiles (can take OutputStream)

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fos); //doesn't compile (can't take OutputStream)
//Need to do this:
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (fos)); //compiles
```

I thought I knew *I/O streams* until I came across this mistake. Can someone explain how `PrintWriter` can write to a **byte stream**, while `BufferedWriter` cannot? Shouldn't they be the same? I always saw them as equal (meaning on internal implementation), but the difference was in methods they possess.

Looks I was wrong :) I see it this way: `BufferedWriter` can't write to byte stream as it is a character stream, meaning someone has to convert those characters. That is why we 'give' `OutputStreamWriter` as a *bridge from character to byte streams*. So, how come `PrintWriter` doesn't need this "bridge". Couldn't they have a way of coding and make our lives easier? Or it is my fault for missing something?

Comment: I think I got it, something cracked in my head :) I can't do it as BufferedWriter is just a decorator class, right? I need a "concrete class" that actually does something. So using BufferedWriter I could even wrap PrintWriter, but I always need class that 'has to do work'. Any close to answering?

Comment: You're right, a `BufferedWriter` can only write to a `Writer` such as `PrintWriter`. It adds buffering to any Writer but it can't (and shouldn't) do text to byte conversion on its own.

Comment: `PrintWriter` has this as a "convenience feature," but it's arguably not even a good idea to provide it at all.  `BufferedWriter` doesn't bother -- it's working-as-intended that you can/should use an `OutputStreamWriter` bridge.

Comment: Right, a `Writer` takes a (raw) stream.  Then wrap the Writer in a `BufferedWriter`.  It's a two step process and sometimes a pain, but the clarity and control are very much worth it imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how come PrintWriter doesn't need this "bridge".

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream)) for the `PrintWriter(OutputStream, ...)` constructors state that they are convenience constructors.  In short, they provide a quick way to do something that you can do another way.

> Couldn't they have a way of coding and make our lives easier?

You are now referring to BufferedWriter not having a convenience constructor that takes an `OutputStream` argument.

As a general rule, convenience constructors and methods are provided for use-cases that are thought to be common enough to warrant this.

In this case, they would potentially need to provide *many* convenience constructors:

- `BufferedWriter(OutputStream)` using the default charset.
- `BufferedWriter(OutputStream, String)` supplying the charset name
- `BufferedWriter(OutputStream, Charset)` supplying the charset
- `BufferedWriter(OutputStream, CharsetEncoder)` supplying the charset encoder directly

and possibly 4 more to supply non-default buffer sizes.

I imagine they did not think this was justifiable.